# How can I get the pathname of the folder two directories upstream of a file?

Tags: python, glob

Using glob2 and os   I would like the directory `'/a/b/'` given the file path `'/a/b/c/xyz.txt'`

I have been able to (recursively) move forward through directories using `/*` and `/**` in glob2, but not backwards through parent directories.  I don't want to use regular expressions or split.  Is there a simple way to do this using glob and/or os?

Comment: `os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname("/a/b/c/xyz.txt"))` ?

Comment: I would really recommend using rsplit though `"/a/b/c/xyz.txt".rsplit("/",2)[0]`

Comment: you're right - i think rsplit makes the most sense.  it is concise and easy for me to read and understand later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why glob?

```
dir_path = file_path.split('/')
what_i_want = '/' + dir_path[10] + '/' + dir_path[1] + '/'
```

You can also do this by finding the index of the 3rd slash, using the return of each call as the "start" argument to the next.

```
third_slash = file_path.index('/', file_path.index('/', file_path.index('/')+1) +1)
what_i_want = file_path[:third_slash+1]
```